# SQL Server : using CTE row partition to serialize sequential timestamps

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, partitioning, dense-rank

I think I just need a little help with this but is there a way to incrementally count steps in SQL using some type of CTE row partition? I'm using SQL Server 2008 so won't be able to use the `LAG` function.

In the below, I am trying to find a way to calculate the Step Number as pictured below where for each unique ITEM in my table, in this case G43251, it calculates the process `Step_Number` based on the Date (timestamp) and the process type. For those with the same timestamp & `process_type`, it would label them both as the same Step_Number as there other fields that could cause the timestamp to repeat twice.

Right now I am playing around with this below and seeing how maybe I could fit in a `DISTINCT` timestamp methodology ? So that it doesn't count each row as something new.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Timestamp_Posted DESC) 
            - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Timestamp_Posted Desc) rn 
    FROM 
        #t1
)
SELECT 
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item, rn ORDER BY Timestamp_Posted DESC) rn2
FROM 
    cte
ORDER BY 
    Timestamp_Posted DESC
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`

```
SELECT *, dense_rank() OVER(Partition By Item ORDER BY Timestamp_Posted, Process_Type ) Step_Number
FROM  #t1
ORDER BY Timestamp_Posted DESC
```